# Contains Search on Calendar Attribute in Spring-Data and QueryDSL

Tags: date, filter, spring-data, querydsl

I would like to use my search field as well on my date attributes using `QueryDSL` and `Spring-Data`. For Example: When there are records with 04.01.2015 and I come in with 201, it should be match, con 2015 contains 201.

Something like this should work:

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
private static BooleanExpression containsStart(final String search) {
    return contract.educationStart.containsIgnoreCase(search);
}
```

My Entity Class looks like follows:

```
@Entity
public class Contract {

    ...

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Calendar educationStart;

    NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Calendar educationEnd;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and I hope maybe it helps others.

My BooleanExpression is now like follows:

```
private static BooleanExpression containsStart(final String search) {
    final BooleanExpression containsDay = contract.educationStart.dayOfMonth().like("%" + search + "%");
    final BooleanExpression containsMonth = contract.educationStart.month().like("%" + search + "%");
    final BooleanExpression containsYear = contract.educationStart.year().like("%" + search + "%");
    return containsDay.or(containsMonth).or(containsYear);
}
```